# Required Checkbox Field Has No Effect

Tags: 7, forms

I used `hook_form_alter` to add a required 'confirmation' checkbox to the node deletion form and the #required status is not honored.

The fields/fieldset are property displayed 'node-delete-confirmation' form.

Here is the hook_form_alter content:

```
$form['warning'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Warning! - You Must Check The Box Below To Continue'),
    '#weight' => -30,
    '#collapsible' => FALSE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
);
$form['confirm_delete'] = array(
    '#title' => t('I fully understand that this action cannot be undone and that statistics linked to this item will be permanently removed.'),
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => 0,
);
```

How can I enforce the 'required' status so that nodes cannot be deleted until the confirmation is acknowledged.

If I change the code, to completely remove the added fieldset everything works as it should.

Works:

```
$form['warning']['confirm_delete'] = array(
'#title' => t('I fully understand that this action cannot be undone and that statistics linked to this item will be permanently removed.'),
'#type' => 'checkbox',
'#required' => TRUE,
'#default_value' => 0,
```

);

Comment: Seems to work if I completely remove the fieldset.  I would still prefer the fieldset as it looks way better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your form validation handler (hook_form_alter):

```
$form['#validate'] = array('delete_validation_handler') + $form['#validate'];
```

Your validation handler:

```
function delete_validation_handler($form, $form_state){
    if(!$form_state['values']['confirm_delete'])
        form_set_error('confirm_delete', t('Message about to confirm it first'))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one: http://drupaldeveloper.in/codelet/drupal-make-single-checkbox-required-field
It will always work!
Please note, its for Drupal 6.x, but you can use it for 7.x as well!